# pandas dataframe subplot grouping by columns

Tags: pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]])
df.plot(subplots=True)
```

I want subplot by group [0, 1] and [2] columns. is there the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrameGroupBy.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.plot.html) by [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.map.html) by dictionary for 2 groups:

```
mapping = {0:'a', 1:'a', 2:'b'}

df.groupby(df.columns.map(mapping.get), axis=1).plot()
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.columns.map(mapping.get))
Index(['a', 'a', 'b'], dtype='object')
```